# Generate QueryDsl Q Classes From Package

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

How do I generate QueryDsl Q-Classes by only specifying a package name?
Given the source classes reside in my target/generated-sources folder since they are the product of other build plugins (WSDLs, XSDs, etc.)

I have tried using the following plugins, but can't find the right configuration:

```
<groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
<executions>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <processor>${com.mysema.query.apt.ProcessorClass}</processor>
    </configuration>
</executions>
```

and:

```
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>1.0.4</version>
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <packageName>com.my.package</packageName>
    <sourceFolder>target/generated-sources</sourceFolder>
    <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/querydsl</targetFolder>
</configuration>
```

...which would generate the classes:

- com.my.package.QFoo.java
- com.my.package.QBar.java

Since there's no common JPA or JDO annotation, and I don't have have access to the source files, I haven't been able to use any of the `com.mysema.query.apt.*Processor`s for the maven-apt-plugin's `<processor>`.

***EDIT 1:** added full maven-apt-plugin configuration.*

***EDIT 2:*** 
- I was able to get the maven-apt-plugin to work sporadically via the maven command line, but not Eclipse/STS by extending `AbstractQuerydslProcessor` to look for `@XmlType`-annotated classes.  Double code-generation is admittedly not an ideal solution.

Comment: Could you post your full configuration for maven-apt-plugin? Also use the newest version https://github.com/mysema/maven-apt-plugin/

Comment: @TimoWestkämper - updated per Edit 1.

Comment: Edit 3: Also looked into [BeanAnnotationProcessor](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.mysema.rdf%7Crdfbean-core%7C1.6.1%7Cjar) per the [example](https://github.com/mysema/maven-apt-plugin), but ran into an [issue](https://github.com/mysema/maven-apt-plugin/issues/17).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to generate the Q-classes using the strategy Timo outlined here: https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/196

In my module's `package-info.java`:

```
@QueryEntities({ com.remote.module.Foo.class,
    com.remote.module.Bar.class })
package com.my.local.module.querydsl;

import com.mysema.query.annotations.QueryEntities;
```

The plugin execution in the Maven POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>apt-maven-plugin-remote-module-QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <!-- genereate Q-classes specified in package-info.java -->
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: target/generated-sources is not an optimal choice for a target directory, consider using sub directory. Also fix the version of the plugin, to have more deterministic results.

Comment: @Timo: The plugin version is managed by the parent POM's plugin dependencies.  Curious why target/generated-sources is not optimal.

Comment: Subfolders of target/generated-sources should be used instead, using this pattern you avoid situations where your target folder is inside a source folder